# How to test/validate many spring context?

Tags: spring, junit

I have created a java component which it will be use by other people.
And I would like to perform unit-testing to verify many spring configurations.

What I've done today : One class test by configuration file

- config 01 : Config01Test.java
- config 02 : Config02Test.java
- config 03 : Config03Test.java

  ```
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/spring/config01.xml" })
  @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
  public class Config01Test{
  }

  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/spring/config02.xml" })
  @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
  public class Config02Test{

  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/spring/config03.xml" })
  @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
  public class Config03Test{}
  ```

But I was wondered if it we could done it in one java class.
As for example load a different spring context for each test :
(with a Junit Annotation ... like @LoadSpringContext( blablabla )

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD) 
public class ConfigTest{

    @LoadSpringContext(locations = {"/spring/config01.xml")
    public testConfig01(){
      // implement test
    }

    @LoadSpringContext(locations = {"/spring/config02.xml")
    public testConfig02(){
      // implement test
    }

    @LoadSpringContext(locations = {"/spring/config03.xml")
    public testConfig03(){
      // implement test
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Spring annotations: `@RunWith`, `@DirtiesContext`, `@LoadSpringContext` and load the spring context by hand in every test case.

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/application-context.xml");
```

Comment: I can load many application context with that.

However, I have an "ApplicationContextAware" defined (to load a parameter file), witch it is not initialised when I use this technique.